# How to access the location of a currently open file in XText

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I am supposed to read the currently open DSL File to create an Auto Populate Feature. For that I am supposed to find the location of the file programmatically and then read it. However there seems to be no alternatives for this purpose. If I use Eclipse Plugin Methods, I get the following error `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.ui.editor.XbaseEditor cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile`
Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to determine the file that any editor is editing is:

```
IEditorPart editor = get the editor

IEditorInput editorInput = editor.getEditorInput();

if (editorInput instanceof IFileEditorInput)
 {
   IFile file = ((IFileEditorInput)editorInput).getFile();

   // TODO handle file
 }
```